# Configure HAproxy for Redis with deferent Auth keys

Tags: redis, haproxy, node-redis

I have Redis cluster of three instances and the cluster is powered by Redis Sentinel and they are running as [master,slave,slave].

Also and HAproxy instance is running to transfer the traffic to the master node, and those tow slaves are read only, are used by another applications.

It was very easy to configure HAproxy to select the **Master Node** when same auth key used for all instance, but now we have different auth keys for every instance different from others.

```
#listen redis-16    
 bind ip_address:6379 name redis
  mode    tcp
 default_backend bk_redis_16

backend bk_redis_16
# mode    tcp
 option tcp-check
 tcp-check connect
 tcp-check send AUTH\ auth_key\r\n
 tcp-check send PING\r\n
 tcp-check expect string +PONG
 tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
 tcp-check expect string role:master
 tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
 tcp-check expect string +OK
 server R1 ip_address:6379  check inter 1s
 server R2 ip_address:6380 check inter 1s
 server R3 ip_address:6381 check inter 1s
```

So the above code works only when we have one passwords across {R1,R2,R3}, How to configuer HAproxy for different passwords.

I mean how to make HAproxy use the the each auth key for its server, like the following:

R1 : abc

R2 : klm

R3 : xyz

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary options:

1. Set up an HA Proxy config for each set of servers which have different passwords.
2. Set up HA Proxy to not use auth but rather pass all connections through transparently.

You have other problems with the setup you list. Your read-only slaves will not have a role of "master". Thus even if you could assign each a different password, your check would refuse the connection. Also, in the case of a partition your check will allow split-brain conditions.

When using HA Proxy in front of a Sentinel managed Redis pod[1] if you try to have HA Proxy figure out where to route connections to you must have HA Proxy check *all* Sentinels to ensure that the Redis instance the majority of Sentinels have decided is indeed the master. Otherwise you can suffer from split-brain where two or more instances report themselves as the Master. There is actually a moment after a failover when you can see this happen.

If your master goes down and a slave is promoted, when the master comes back up it will report itself as master until Sentinel detects the master and reconfigures it to be a slave. During this time your HA Proxy check will send writes to the original master. These writes will be lost when Sentinel reconfigures it to be a slave.

For the case of option 1:
You can either run a separate configured instance of HA Proxy or you can set up front ends and multiple back ends (paired up). Personally I'd go with multiple instances of HA Proxy as it allows you to manage them without interference with each other.

For the case of option 2:
You'll need to glue Sentinel's notification mechanism to HA Proxy being reconfigured. This can easily be done using a script triggered on Sentinel to reach out and reconfigure HA Proxy on the switch-master event. The details on doing this are at http://redis.io/topics/sentinel and more directly at the bottom of the example file found at http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/sentinel.conf

In a Redis Pod + Sentinel setup with direct connectivity the clients are able to gather the information needed to determine where to connect to. When you place a non-transparent proxy in between them your proxy needs to be able to make those decisions - or have them made for it when topology changes occur - on behalf of the client.

1. Note: what you describe is not a Redis cluster, it is a replication setup. A Redis cluster is entirely different. I use the term "pod" to apply to a replication based setup.